# Getting member roles from 'wix-users'

Tags: velo

I've been trying to make a page that displays different elements based on different users' member roles. Currently, I have two member roles: the default "Member" and a new role "Sponsors". I've gotten the member roles using the wix-users module as such.

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady(function () {
    //TODO: write your page related code here...
    var roleName;
    let currentUser = wixUsers.currentUser;

    currentUser.getRoles()
    .then( (roles) => {
    var firstRole = roles[0];
    roleName = firstRole.name;                // "Role Name"
    console.log(roleName);
    var roleDescription = firstRole.description;  // "Role Description"
  }).catch(
      onFailure()
  );



  if(roleName === "Sponsors"){
      $w('#text13').show();
  }

});
```

I know that the promise from getRoles() is resolving based on my debugging, and the `console.log(roleName)` is logging "Sponsors" to the console correctly when I'm logged in. **However, it seems that the if statement of** `if(roleName === "Sponsors")` **will not run, whatever I do.** What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've run into a Promises issue. The `getRoles()` function is an asynchronous one. That means it doesn't return a value right away. That is also why it has a `.then()`. The code in the `.then()` is only run after the Promise returned by `getRoles()` resolves to a value.

You might want to check out some resources about JavaScript Promises. Wix Code also has an [article](https://support.wix.com/en/article/working-with-promises-in-wix-code) describing how to work with Promises specifically tailored to Wix Code.

The code where you check if the `roleName` is `"Sponsors"` actually runs before the code where you set the value of `roleName`. That's why it doesn't work. You need to pull that code up into the `.then()`.

```
currentUser.getRoles()
  .then( (roles) => {
     var firstRole = roles[0];
     roleName = firstRole.name;      
     if(roleName === "Sponsors"){
       $w('#text13').show();
  } );
```

Alternatively, you can use `async`/`await` to deal with the asynchronous code.

Note that this example still might not work because you are only checking the users first role. If the user has multiple roles I don't think there is any guarantee that `"Sponsors"` will be the first role.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Web development and JS in general is completely new to me, thank you so much :D